# When I edit a post in Stack Overflow, who reviews that for its verification?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

When I edit a post in stack communities such as [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), I am encountered with the following text:

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>
> This edit will be visible only to you until it is [peer-reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

My question is: Who reviews that for its verification?

---

[**NOTE**]:
I read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) question but it didn't satisfy my question.

Comment: @Nathaniel hmm, I searched that but not found any thing, so my keywords to this question is not good, and I think my question is forming with other keywords for some people like me to searching.

Comment: @Nathaniel no, my question is not same.

Comment: For questions about core Stack Exchange functionality, it's a good idea to search within the [tag:faq] tag on this site; it has the most useful posts detailing a wide variety of functionality.

Comment: Why doesn't the other question answer your question?

Comment: The section that is titled "Who can vote on a suggested edit?" is the answer to your question. Also, one of the great things about duplicates is that they stick around, so they act as pointers to the main question for users who do have different keywords.